# Best Way to Test ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I'm running into issues developing tests for ManyToManyField entries. I have a simple blog model like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    text = models.TextField()
```

I've created some very basic tests just for the sheer hell of it:

```
class EntryTests(TestCase):
    def testEntryFields(self):
        user1 = User.objects.create_user('xs', 'ln@gmail.com', 'pw')
        user1.last_name = 'H'
        user1.save()

        now = timezone.now()
        entry1 = Entry(title="Title", author=user1, pubdate=now, text="Hello")
        entry1.save()
        tag1 = entry1.tags.create(name="testtag")
        tag1.save()

        self.assertEqual(entry1.title, "Title")
        self.assertEqual(entry1.pubdate, now)
        self.assertEqual(entry1.text, "Hello")
        self.assertEqual(entry1.author, user1)
        self.assertEqual(entry1.tags.all()[0], tag1)
        self.assertEqual(tag1.name, "testtag")
```

This passes, but as you can see, I've had to do some weird gymnastics (generating a list of all of the entries and taking the first, and only, entry in that list) to test for equality on `entry1.tags`. Is there a better way to do this with Django?

Comment: Naturally. This is a trivial example. But later on in the code when I'm testing for something I've put in the m2m field through various functions, I'd like to know how to do it optimally.

Comment: Oh. That comment disappeared, but I'll keep that there to remind people that I'm not actually concerned with writing tests to test Django's basic functionality.

Comment: hmm, but what exactly are you trying to test? atm you ARE just testing core Django functionality. Are you going to extend this classes somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand either what's the difference between what do you want to test, and the normal behavior of django models...

but isn't a simple field lookup better for that assertion?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

```
self.assertEqual(entry1.tags.get(pk=tag1.pk), tag1)
```

also, there're some custom assertions inside django's unittest:
[assertQuerySetEqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerySetEqual) might be more appropriate when using `.all` or `.filter`